# Regex - Return entire line starting with certain phrase

Tags: regex

I've been looking around for quite some time, yet I can't find a regex "expression" to return the entire line if it starts with a certain phrase.

For example:

```
Members online: ***Test test_123 , **Nibblesnow , *Bad
```

I've had a look around, searching however I still cannot find a expression to successfully work.

I've been trying to use regex101.com to figure the expression but I've got no look.

It needs to start with ^ and end with $ so I can return the $1 in the output action. **Is there a way to retrieve the information after the "Members online: " and get it using $1**

Comment: What programming language are you using? What is `$1`?

Comment: I know it's going to sound dumb, but I don't entirely know.

`[Match]
regex=^Members.+?(?=\<br\>|\<br\s*\/\>|$)
action=send Members online: $1`

and I was hoping it would return everything after it.

Comment: Try `^Members online:(.+)`

Comment: Didn't work Wiktor (thanks btw <3)

https://i.imgur.com/3i7p8hX.png I'm trying to find that line (using the expression) then somehow returning everything after the actual `Members online: ` part.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to exactly match "Members Online: " then that's all you have to put in your regex: `/^Members online: (.*?)$/`

`$1` (or whatever first match is in your language) will be the value of everything after the starting phrase until the end of the line. In the example use case, that would be:

`***Test test_123 , **Nibblesnow , *Bad`

Comment: @Gertius `^Members online: (.*?)$` = `^Members online: (.*)` if `.` does not match line breaks (and usually, it does not).

Comment: @Gertius Happy to help! Don't forget to accept the answer!